# How can I add in rgl device several subsets of data as spheres or points? add=T is not working

Tags: 3d, rgl

I need help with my rgl.spheres. I have the code below, and adding a set of data as spheres inside a rgl device is working (for the whole dataset) in 3D. I just created subsets of this data and wanted to plot them in different colors, and even customize them to add per subset a ellipse.

Like usual in the "normal" R-plots in 2D, I just open the plot like

`plot(x,y, col="red", cex=1, ...)` with the "points" command I add each subset below the initial plot. The same structure I wanted to use for the rgl device, but even inside the `rgl.spheres(....add=T)` is not working. Has anybody an idea to overcome this? Best regards and in advance a big thank you for your help, Chris

I tried already using in `rgl.spheres(... add=T)` and tried to find (for myself) logical commands like add.spheres(...) or rgl.add.spheres(...) but these ones are obviously not working.

```
rgl.open()
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<-c(9,5,2,7,7,3)
z<-c(0.1,1,1,4,6,7)
x1 <- 1
y1 <- 9
z1 <- 0.1

rgl.spheres(x,y,z, r = 0.1, color = "grey")
rgl.spheres(x1,y1,z1, r=0.1, color="red", add=T) # is not working
```

so if there is a similar command like the "points" command for the spheres or other objects in rgl ,there should be one red sphere and some grey spheres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read the vignette about `rgl`, using `vignette("rgl", package="rgl")`.  But a quick summary:

- Don't use the `rgl.*` functions.  They are low-level functions, and will cause you problems unless you are very familiar with how they work.  Use the `*3d` functions, e.g. `open3d`, `spheres3d`, etc.
- Most drawing functions (including `spheres3d`) always add to the current scene.  You don't need `add = TRUE`.
- By default, whatever gets drawn first will be shown if two things are drawn at the same spot.  Since both of your instructions to draw spheres include the point `(1, 9, 0.1)`, only the first will show up.  You can override this by 
  making the second statement draw a bigger sphere (whose near side will be closer to the viewer, so visible), or by playing with the setting for the material property `depth_test`. Setting `depth_test = "lequal"` means that the last thing drawn will be shown.

Putting all of this together, here's a revision of your code:

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<-c(9,5,2,7,7,3)
z<-c(0.1,1,1,4,6,7)
x1 <- 1
y1 <- 9
z1 <- 0.1

spheres3d(x,y,z, r = 0.1, color = "grey")
spheres3d(x1,y1,z1, r=0.1, color="red", depth_test = "lequal")
```

Comment: Dear user2554330, i think, you helped me last time as well! Thank you very very much for your help! This is absolutely insane and I apollogize for my spelling mistakes. Thank you also for this correcture! Now it is working, thank you really much again :), best regards, Chris